# Does mongodb have a product equivalent of the aggregate $sum

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to calculate cumulative returns for a portfolio of stocks in mongodb and ideally would be able to use a cumulative $product accumulator

**e.g.** If I have three documents one with the value 0.5, the next 0.6 and the final having 0.7

I can easily calculate the sum using the aggregate accumulator `$sum`. This will give **0.5+0.6+0.7**.

What I would like to do is calculate the cumulative product (**$product**) of these values i.e. **0.5*0.6*0.5**? Can this be done directly of do I have to use logs?

The document structure is something like the following

```
{
   "date" : 2015-12-31T15:50:00.000Z,
   "time" : 1550,
   "aum"  : 1000000,
   "basket" :[
   {
     "_id" : "Microsoft",
     "return" : 0.03,
     "shares" : 10,
     "price"  : 56.53,
     "fx"     : 1.0
   },
   .
   .
   .
   {
     "_id" : "GOOG.N",
     "return" : 0.05,
     "shares" : 20,
     "price"  : 759.69,
     "fx"     : 1.0
   }
```

Comment: The documents I'm talking about are the embedded documents "basket". I want to form a cumulative product on the field "return"

Comment: Unfortunately, https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10681 gets in the way of doing this easily.

Comment: I ended up altering the mathematics to do it using sum. As I have returns in my calculation I can use the identity log(A.B.C) = log(A)+log(b)+log(c)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [$multiply (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/)

```
> db.stocks.aggregate( {$project: { total: { $multiply: [ 0.5,0.6,0.5 ] } }} )
```

**UPDATE:**

This will calculate product of each stock in a separate document:

```
> var total=1;db.stocks.find().forEach(function(doc){total=total*doc.stock;})
> total
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as the return for each stock is in a separate document. I need to be able to produce a cumulative product over the set of documents

Comment: okais...but I am not getting you...you told that you can easily calculate the sum using the aggregate accumulator $sum...can you show it? so I can understand your question in more brief.

Answer (score -3):

you need to use $multiply and below is a sample query

db.stocks.aggregate(  [{ total: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } }  ])